# Accessing local host via external ip?

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, nat

I'm trying to access a host in my local network (my own machine in fact) via the external ip that my dsl router NATs to, so the set up is the following:

```
                      /----------------------------/
/-------------/       /          Router            /    /----------/
/    Host     /-------/ 192.168.1.2 | 79.44.63.132 /----/ Internet /  
/ 192.168.1.1 /       / internal ip | external ip  /    /----------/
/-------------/       /----------------------------/
```

On my router I have enabled port forwarding for port 1234, such that
traffic to 79.44.63.132:1234 gets mapped to 192.168.1.1:1234. I can access 79.44.63.132:1234 from the outside as expected, but when I try to access it from within the network *something* goes wrong. More specifically, when I

```
telnet 79.44.63.132 1234
```

from 192.168.1.1, I get a connection to my own machine, but it doesn't respond. Inspecting the traffic reveals that the router doesn't actually drop any packets, it NATs as if the traffic came from the outside, i.e. fort forwarding and network address translation result in packets being rewritten like

```
/-------------------------/      /--------------------------/
/ payload: 10001010110101 /      / payload: 10001010110101  /
/ from: 192.168.1.1:44713 / |--> / from: 79.44.63.132:63944 /
/   to: 79.44.63.132:1234 /      /   to: 192.168.1.1:1234   /
/-------------------------/      /--------------------------/
```

and

```
/--------------------------/      /-------------------------/
/ payload: 00110110101101  /      / payload: 00110110101101 /
/ from: 192.168.1.1:1234   / |--> / from: 79.44.63.132:1234 /
/   to: 79.44.63.132:63944 /      /   to: 192.168.1.1:44713 /
/--------------------------/      /-------------------------/
```

So, it seems as if it should work, but it doesn't. What could have gone wrong here?

Comment: https://docs.connectwise.com/ConnectWise_Control_Documentation/On-premises/On-premises_knowledge_base/Cannot_access_external_IP_address_from_LAN

Comment: As I wrote, loopback works, i.e. there is no packet loss and I can initially connect to myself over an external ip, but then the connection "freezes".

Comment: Are there any iptables chains set? Any packet deep inspection running? What does `iptables -L` output?

Comment: I would like to be able to answer this question, but if I could do that, I could also solve my issue by simply setting up a static route. The problem is, it's one of these DSL routers your ISP gives you; I can't look inside it (unless I find a way to hack it).

Comment: I meant the local PC. Could there be some filter recognizing that the origin of the request is actually from local and thus detecting some apparent ip spoofing? It might also be a routing loop protection. Does it work from another host in the local net?

Comment: No, it doesn't work from any other host I've tried (iOS, macOS). Probably best to write my own test program to figure out what's going on.